# How XMLHttpRequest works in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

im programming an app which uses XMLHttpRequest to connect with a server to receive data.
The Problem is that I only get in the readyState attribute the value 2. That means the connection with the server is established but no data is streaming yet.
The value I need is 3, that means the request is been processed, but never happens.
Anyone knows why this append?
Thanks.

```
var otro="hello Marcos";
var datosNTRIP="Hello World";
var url = "http://ntrip.itacyl.es:2101/ponf1"
function httpGet(theUrl)
{

    var bucle = 0;
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open( "GET", theUrl, true); // false for synchronous request 
   xml.onreadystatechange=function(e)
    {

        datosNTRIP=xml.readyState;
        if(xml.readyState === 3)
            {
                bucle+=1;
                if(bucle<=lim && xml.status === 200)
                    {
  //                      resultado.innerHTML="Sending data";
                        //alert(xml.responseText);
                       // break;
                    }
                else if((bucle>lim)||(bucle>lim && xml.status!=200))
                {
                    xml.abort();
                }

            }

    postMessage(datosNTRIP);
    };
    xml.onerror = function(e)
    {
     //   alert("error");   
    };
    xml.send( null );


}
httpGet(url);
```

Comment: Show what you have coded, so far.

Comment: @laruiss there it is

Comment: The URL example you have provided requires a username/password -- that may be your issue.

Comment: You probably have some SOP problem with that domain and port.

Comment: What is this `postMessage`?

Comment: I got a user and pass to pass @payne . I can establish the connection with the server.

Comment: @Bergi postMessage is the function wich sends the data to the HTML. this code is a WebWorker of JavaScript